# What is the ring of invariants under the action of an arbitrary subgroup of the symmetric group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory

Let $A$ be a commutative unitary ring and $A[t_1, t_2, ..., t_n]$ the polynomial ring over $A$ in $n$ variables. The symmetric group of degree $n$ acts on $A[t_1, t_2, ..., t_n]$ in a natural way and the ring of invariants under this action is well understood. If we restrict the action to an arbitrary subgroup $G$ of the symmetric group of degree $n$, what are known results for the ring of invariants under this action? Can we classify them in some sense?

Comment: After having written an answer, I think this question belongs on MathOverflow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $G\subset S_n$ be the permutation group in question. Let $A[\mathbf{t}]:=A[t_1,\dots,t_n]$ as a shorthand.

General results:

(a) The invariant ring $A[\mathbf{t}]^G$ is generated by the invariants of degree at most $\operatorname{max}(n,n(n-1)/2)$, a result usually attributed to Manfred Gobel (see [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82598741.pdf)), although it was actually anticipated by Leopold Kronecker (see section 12 of his paper Grundzuge einer arithmetischen theorie der algebraischen grossen, *Crelle, Journal fur die reine und angewandte Mathematik* 92:1-122, 1881, reprinted in *Werke*, vol. 2, 237–387).

(b) If the coefficient ring $A$ is a field of characteristic not dividing the group order $|G|$, then $A[\mathbf{t}]^G$ is free as a module over the subring generated by any homogeneous system of parameters (equivalently, $A[\mathbf{t}]^G$ is Cohen-Macaulay). This result is not specific to permutation groups -- it is a consequence of the Hochster-Eagon theorem. (Though again it happens that Kronecker proved it in the case of a permutation group and a field of characteristic 0.) Then any homogeneous system of parameters for $A[\mathbf{t}]^G$ is called a set of **primary invariants**, and a module basis over the subring they generate is a set of **secondary invariants**. There are algorithms based on Grobner bases to compute primary and secondary invariants, again not specific to permutation groups; see the [book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642077968) by Derksen and Kemper. *However*, in the case of permutation groups, the elementary symmetric polynomials provide a uniform choice for the primary invariants, and there is a method due to Nicolas Borie that aims for more effective computability of the secondary invariants (see [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-23021-4_6)).

(c) There is also a method due to Garsia and Stanton that produces secondary invariants from a shelling of a certain cell complex (specifically, the quotient of the barycentric subdivision of the boundary of an $(n-1)$-simplex by the $G$ action on the simplex's vertices), when such exists (see [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0001870884900057?via%3Dihub)). When this shelling exists, the assumption that $A$ be a field of characteristic not dividing $|G|$ becomes superfluous, i.e. the secondary invariants produced by the method give a module basis for $A[\mathbf{t}]^G$ over the subring generated by the elementary symmetric polynomials, entirely regardless of $A$. It is not an easy problem to find the shelling in general, but has been done in specific cases (the original paper by Garsia and Stanton handles the Young subgroups $Y\subset S_n$ [i.e., direct products of smaller symmetric groups acting on disjoint sets of indices], [work of Vic Reiner](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Ereiner/Papers/MyThesis.pdf) handles alternating subgroups $Y^+\subset S_n$ of Young subgroups $Y$, and diagonally embedded Young subgroups $Y \hookrightarrow Y\times Y \hookrightarrow S_n\times S_n\subset S_{2n}$, and [work](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1025044720847) of Patricia Hersh handles the wreath product $S_2\wr S_n\subset S_{2n}$). There is a detailed development of Garsia and Stanton's shelling result in [my thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.08417.pdf), sections 2.5 and 2.8, along with a discussion of its connection to Gobel's work (see last paragraph) and some speculation about generalizations.

(d) From (b) you can see that $A[\mathbf{t}]^G$ has a nice structure of free-module-over-polynomial-subring when $A$ is a field of characteristic not dividing $|G|$, but from (c) you can see that *sometimes* this nice structure still exists even when $A$ doesn't satisfy this (e.g. perhaps it is $\mathbb{Z}$, or else a field whose characteristic *does* divide $|G|$). There is a [characterization](https://msp.org/ant/2018/12-7/p10.xhtml), due to myself and Sophie Marques, of which groups $G\subset S_n$ have the property that this structure in $A[\mathbf{t}]^G$ exists regardless of $A$. It turns out to be the groups generated by transpositions, double transpositions, and 3-cycles.

(Our paper is framed in the language of Cohen-Macaulay rings and is focused on the situation that $A$ is a field. To see that my claim about "any $A$" in the previous paragraph follows, one shows that if for a given $G$, the described structure obtains for $A$ any field, then it also obtains with $A=\mathbb{Z}$ -- this is supposedly well-known, but "just in case", it is written down carefully in section 2.4.1 of my thesis -- and then one notes that a free module basis of $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbf{t}]^G$ over the subring generated by the elementary symmetric polynomials will also be a free module basis of $A[\mathbf{t}]^G$, just by base changing to $A$. See [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466048/permutation-groups-acting-on-polynomial-rings-and-base-change) for why the base change doesn't mess anything up.)

(e) As lisyarus stated, the special case of $G=A_n$ is well-understood: the invariant ring is generated by the elementary symmetric polynomials and the Vandermonde determinant. Actually this requires the hypothesis that $2$ is a unit in $A$, as you note in comments. If $2$ is not a unit in $A$, one can still generate the invariant ring with the elementary symmetric polynomials and the sum of the positive terms in the Vandermonde determinant (or, the sum of the negative terms). Certain other cases, e.g. $D_4$, also have explicit descriptions coming from Galois theory. The classical material usually assumes $A$ is a field, but see sections 5.4 and 5.5 in [Owen Biesel's thesis](https://search.proquest.com/docview/1367595938?pq-origsite=gscholar) for $A_n$ and $D_4$; Biesel is working over general $A$.

I am not sure what you're hoping for in terms of a classification theorem.

(This was really probably more of an MO than an MSE question in the end.)

Comment: For $G = S_n$ we dont need any conditions on the caracteristic of $A$ as far as i am aware. Also do we have similar results if $A$ is a ring and not a field?

Comment: That is correct about $S_n$, but in general the characteristic matters. (See the added material in the answer, in particular part (d). Note that $S_n$ is generated by transpositions, and $A_n$ by 3-cycles.) The smallest permutation group for which the characteristic matters is $C_4=\langle (1234)\rangle \subset S_4$, see section 2.2 here: http://algant.eu/documents/theses/ferrario.pdf

Comment: I am working on this topic in the language of splitting algebras (see https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211125). I came across the following. Let $\mathbb{S}:=\{S_{M_1}\times ... \times S_{M_k} \subseteq S_n \mid M_1 \sqcup M_2 \sqcup ... \sqcup M_n = \{1, 2, ..., n\} \}$. For $G, H \in \mathbb{S}$ with $G\subseteq H$ we can write $A[t]^G$ over $A[t]^H$ with a certain base. For an aribitrary group $G\subseteq S_n$ we can write $A[t]^G$ as a certain lift of invariants for groups in $\mathbb{S}$. However i cant assess wether this result can be found in current literature because of lack of knowledge.

Comment: A partial result would be a calssification of $A[t]^{A_n}$, namely $A[t]^{A_n} = A[t]^{S_n} + \left( \sum_{\sigma \in A_n} \sigma \right) A[t].$ This is a conesquence of the fact that $G A_n = S_n$ for all $G\in \mathbb{S}$ but $G = \{\text{id} \}$. It is fairly easy to calculate $\left( \sum_{\sigma \in A_n} \sigma \right) A[t]$. We obtain $\left( \sum_{\sigma \in A_n} \sigma \right) A[t] = A[t]^{S_n} + \left( \sum_{\sigma \in A_n}\sigma(t_2 t_3^2 ... t_n^{n-1}) \right)  A[t]^{S_n}$.

Comment: By "classification" I guess you mean a set of secondary invariants (i.e. a free module basis) over the ring of symmetric polynomials $A[\mathbf{t}]^{S_n}$? (For $A_n$ this is $\left\{1,\sum_{\sigma\in A_n} \sigma(t_2\dots t_n^{n-1})\right\}$ as you said.) Such secondary invariants can be given independently of $A$ if and only if $G$ is generated by transpositions, double transpositions, and 3-cycles, by the result quoted in (d). (This is why $C_4\subset S_4$ is the first counterexample.)

Comment: If it would be good enough to have a module *generating set* over $A[\mathbf{t}]^{S_n}$ rather than a *basis*, then a uniform answer is given by the "special monomials" in Manfred Gobel's paper, linked both in my answer and in lisyarus', but they are not linearly independent over $A[\mathbf{t}]^{S_n}$.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "lift", but your result sounds interesting to me and my guess is it is not in the literature (but of course I cannot be sure). The paper of Garsia and Stanton I mentioned gives secondary invariants for $A[\mathbf{t}]^\mathbb{S}$ itself. If you publish your result or post a preprint, please post a link here!

Comment: Thanks alot for all of your detailed answers. I am going to post a preprint however it will entail more general results about invariants in the language of splitting algebras which might not be of interest to you and it will take quiet some time. The invariants of the polynomial ring are a special case and I would love to message you the general ideas and results so you could asses wether they are new and of interest or not.

Comment: @kevkev1695 - please feel free to do so! You can find my email here: https://cds.nyu.edu/math-democracy-seminar/

Answer (score 3):

For the special case of the alternating group $G=A_n$, it is known that elementary symmetric polynomials, together with the Vandermonde determinant $V=\prod\limits_{i<j}(t_i - t_j)$ form a generating set for the ring of invariants. I don't know whether those are still algebraically independent, i.e. that the invariants are freely-generated.

For the general case of an arbitrary subgroup $G \subset S_n$, see [*Manfred Göbel, Computing Bases for Rings of Permutation-invariant Polynomials*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717185710176).

Comment: In answer to your implicit question, the Vandermonde determinant satisfies a quadratic relation over the subring generated by the elementary symmetric polynomials.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith Indeed, since $V^2$ is invariant under $S_n$. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will look into the text. For the case of $G=A_n$ the Vaneremonde determinant is only sufficient if $2$ is invertible in $A$ as far as i am aware. Otherwise you need something like $\prod_{\sigma \in A_n} \sigma (t_2 t_3^2 ... t_n^{n-1})$ or $\left( \prod_{i<j} (t_i+t_j) + \prod_{i<j} (t_i-t_j) \right)/2$.